# Without using database how Can I Search for a word and display it's related content in another field

Tags: c#, .net, file, dictionary

So the question can be reformatted as "**What can replace a database in an offline version?**"

The initial idea is inspired from [wordweb](http://wordweb.info/) where you just type the word and then you get the meaning of it displayed in a fraction.

Of-course they are not saving all the words and there meanings in a database. What are they using? Are they storing all the values in a file and retrieving the corresponding meaning?

Is there any article which shows the above approach(Reading a particular section of a file ).

Are they using HashTables or similar?

Comment: Why are they not saving their data in a database? If you know this for sure, then you must know how they implement it.

Comment: @Matt Ellen, I am not quite sure as could not spot any mdf or mdb files after installation. Though few answers directed toward sqllite I can not deny that possibility of using database anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You could utilize a local database such as SQLite or you could utilize a text file and store your data in it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use an embedded database to store words and meanings. Try to look at [Sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/). It's simple to use, just require to include a dll in your setup, and has [a wrapper to use it from c#](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/).
It is very stable ,fast and widely used.

Comment: @Meakins, I don't see a reason to downvote the posts as they answered at the same time as you did. I should strongly sugegest to cancel the downvotes as they vioalte the community guidelines http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @Meakins, I didn't copy your solution, I'm just writing my solution while you wrote your. In fact, we both are suggesting a very commonly used database engine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what it is they are using, but there is at least SQLite, a database engine that doesn't require installing any server or other program, since it gets compiled into your executable and uses a single file for the database. That's as close as you'll get to an actual database with nothing but filesystem access.
Otherwise, if the amount of data isn't too large, you could store it in a file format that isn't too hard to parse (such as XML, although the overhead is considerable), load all your data into memory, and then use .NETs built-in DataSet functionality, or better yet, Linq to objects or Linq to datasets to manipulate the data.